# Use always Windows Explorer-style Open/Save dialog box

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

There are two types of "Open file" dialogs.

One is "Windows Explorer-style dialog"
[image]

The other, "Places bar dia
[image]

I would like to use always the Windows Explorer-style dialog, since it is customizable and there is space for a lot of items.

I has been searching in Google without luck. I found [a guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/97824/how-to-customize-the-file-opensave-dialog-box-in-windows/) to modify the places bar, but it isnt what I want.

Comment: This belongs on Stack Overflow since you ask about achieving the effect in your own application

Comment: @kinokijuf are you sure?  I don't see any reference to the OP trying to do this as part of a programming project.  I am reading like the OP is trying to force windows to prefer 1 style over the other in any application.

Comment: @psubsee2003 but this is impossible, you can’t change the code of other applications

Comment: @kinokijuf then we need the OP to clarify.  But the impossibility of it doesn't automatically mean he is trying to do it for an app he is developing.

Comment: psubsee2003 is right. It may have not been implemented but i think it is possible. Some "Open file" dialogs are hard coded, but the ones showed in captures are used by most programs so I think it could be easier to change (with a hack for example).